# How to store span id value in to PHP variable

Tags: php

I want to know how to store span/div id value in to PHP variable....in id=event_id there is value like '234'... so i want store that value in to php variable

```
  <?php
 //This Statement stores data in variable
 $test = '<span id ="event_id" ></span>'; 
 //this is for printing variable that contains data
 echo $test;
?>

<script>
 function setEventId(event_id){
  document.querySelector('#event_id')= event_id;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Do you mean you want to store `event_id` in a different variable

Comment: in id=event_id there is value like '234'... so i want store that value in to php variable

Comment: Ok, I think you will have to give us a more descriptive example

Comment: You can use `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML, then use `getAttribute('id')` to get the ID value.

Comment: But if PHP is creating the element, can't you get the event ID from the variable that was used to create the string?

Comment: I feel like you're trying to achieve something else but asking a wrong question.What are you going to do with the $test variable afterwards?

Comment: No... there is a value in event_id... so i m trying to save this value in to $test

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
<?php
 //This Statement stores data in variable 
 $test = '<span id ="event_id" ></span>';
 //this is for printing variable that contains data
 echo $test;
 $event_id = "<script>document.writeln(document.getElementById('event_id').innerHTML)</script>";
?>
```

Comment: No... you did not understand

Comment: Do you want to grab event_id from span as text?

Comment: NO...there is value save event_id .... i want that  value save in variable

Comment: <span id ="event_id" >234</span>
Your span looks like this and you want this 234 to store in php variable?

Comment: $event_id = "<script>document.getElementById('event_id');</script>";

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: event_id is a jquery id so there is value store in event_id... so i want get that value in store in variable

Comment: Yes i've updated the answer you can try it.

Comment: Got it working finally
$event_id = "<script>document.writeln(document.getElementById('event_id').innerHTML)</script>";